# HasOwnProperty Like Javascript

Tags: javascript

Problem :
Different Object Name every Output

```
var data = {'aname':'A','akey':1};

// get object aname
$.each(data, function (i, d) {
  console.log(d.aname);
});

var data = {'bname':'A','bkey':1};

// get object bname
$.each(data, function (i, d) {
  console.log(d.bname);
});
```

This is possible to not repetitive that?
i must get the value with bypass prefix with `hasOwnProperty`, so `aname`, `bname` `*name`, how could this possible? any javascript `hasOwnProperty` like? such as `hasOwnPropert('%name%');`

Comment: `if (data.bname) {`

Comment: `if (obj.aname)` or `if (obj['aname'])` ?

Comment: so if i have 1 million data such as data.cname upto data.zzzzname i must using if?

Comment: im looking for `obj.hasOwnProperty('%name')` in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your object only contains one key with a name containing `name`, the following will do it

```
var data = {'bname':'A','bkey':1};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    if (key.indexOf("name") > -1) {
    console.log(data[key]);
  }
});
```

jQuery:

```
// get object bname
var data = {'bname':'A','bkey':1};

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
  if (key.indexOf("name") > -1) {
    console.log(value);
  }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2r3ksf6k/)

Comment: can u provide the jquery?

Comment: so i must `console.log(d.aname)` again?

Comment: thats my problem to `console` it

Comment: added a demo fiddle

Comment: i is the key of your object, and d is the value @codeK.O.

Comment: yes, i just got confuse.. but now i realize it..
so -1 is not substring. can u explain little?